# Transferring files from virtual Linux computer to Digital Ocean server

Tags: php, linux

I have a virtual Linux computer installed on my Windows PC. Within the Linux computer, I have a working PHP website with several files, templates, etc. I am trying to move this off my own virtual Linux server and onto Digital Ocean, and feel like I'm missing something. Is there some way I can just copy all the folders and files from one system to the other? I am not able to find any kind of 'Windows Explorer'-y file/folder interface using Digital Ocean.

I tried this tutorial but got stuck at the 'put localFile' step:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sftp-to-securely-transfer-files-with-a-remote-server

Does that make sense to anyone? Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a "windows explorer" approximation you could simply use filezilla - Ive used it with digital ocean droplet. once you configure the connection - its pretty much a gui interface.

here is [Digital Ocean tutorial on securely setting up filezilla](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-filezilla-to-transfer-and-manage-files-securely-on-your-vps)

Here is the intro to the page and it sounds like it might apply for your situation:

> Are you a recent cloud hosting convert and find yourself struggling to
>   figure out how to best manage the files on your first virtual private
>   server (VPS)? Do you find yourself intimidated by the command line? If
>   so, you will be happy to learn that FileZilla provides a user-friendly
>   graphical interface that can securely transfer files to-and-from, as
>   well as move files around within, your VPS

Note: Im offering this as a "simplest option possible" answer, I personally dont use filezilla anymore , because it takes forever to transfer files. the other answers mentioned, e.g. `rsync` or zipping and transferring would be how I would do it nowadays - way faster!

Comment: Thank you! All it took was Filezilla and a few head-scratching permissions changes.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to gzip your local site and push it to your `DO` site

say your website is on your local VM in `/var/www/html/..`

so inside of `/var/www` in your VM do

```
root@yourvm:/var/www# tar -zcvf website.tar.gz html
```

then copy the file website.tar.gz to your DO account (this assumes your VM is connected to the internet)

```
root@yourvm:/var/www# scp website.tar.gz username@doserver.com:/home/username/
```

Then when you are logged into DO, extract your website to `/var/www/html/`,

```
root@yourvm:/#tar -zxvf /home/username/website.tar.gz -C /var/www/
```